# Firestore Transaction Error Appears as Empty Object

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I run a transaction inside a `try {} catch(error){}` block in Firestore, I noticed that when I try to store the error in logs, it appears as empty object. However, when I print it into console in the emulator, I get a proper error message.

**Example code:**

```
try {
    await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {
        t.set(myRef, myNewData)
    })
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error) // This prints properly (e.g., "ReferenceError: myRef is not defined")
    functions.logger.error(`Unexpected error occurred:`, { error: error }) // This prints error object as: "error: {}"
}
```

Why does the error object appear empty when using `functions.logger.error()` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this is because your `{ error: error }` object isn't a simple object, which means the logger won't interpret it as a `jsonPayload`.

See more details in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/logger#error) ("If the last argument provided is a plain object, it is added to the `jsonPayload` in the Cloud Logging entry") and in this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/773).

Potential solutions are as follows:

```
functions.logger.error(`Unexpected error occurred:`, error) // Here error is a "simple object"
functions.logger.error(`Unexpected error occurred:`, { error: error.message })
```

or the solution detailed in the Github issue.

Comment: Hey @Sam, did you have time to look at the proposed solutions?